# Shorten the URL from example.com/page.php?var=letters to example.com/letters

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm kinda new to URL Rewriting in .htaccess , and I tried to do it myself following some tutorials. No success though ....

I want to shorten `http://www.example.com/page.php?var=letters` to `http://www.example.com/letters` (*letters* is only an example).

Any help is very welcomed. Can't get this done myself. :(

Answer (score 0):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f # if the requested file does not exist
    RewriteRule ^(.+)$ page.php?var=$1 # rewrite the request
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

A more generic approach, to have all the links you want as domain.tld/person/jon/

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# rewrites all urls to index.php/url
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT]
```

Answer (score 0):

TRiG's answer should get you up and running however, I would strongly suggest you check out:

[.htaccess tips and tricks](http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess.php)

It is an excellent tutorial which should help you get your head round this stuff, part 2 covers mod_rewrite.