# Rewriting friendly URL's using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Shorten the URL from example.com/page.php?var=letters to example.com/letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7162369/shorten-the-url-from-example-com-page-phpvar-letters-to-example-com-letters)

Using htaccess, is it possible to redirect from:

```
http://www.mydomain/123456
```

to

```
http://www.mydomain/myscript.php?id=123456
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7162369/shorten-the-url-from-example-com-page-phpvar-letters-to-example-com-letters) already answers your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use rewrite mod :

```
RewriteRule ^(\d+)$   myscript.php?id=$1
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Aseman! By following a few tutorial and with your help I modified it a little in order to better match the data that should be passed through the URL: RewriteRule ^([0-9]{0,6})$   myscript.php?id=$1 [L]
It's working fine! Thanks for the help!